# Cannot get disableClassMetadata to take effect

Tags: playn

I am writing a basic game based on the "Hello" PlayN demo which uses the TriplePlay UI.  When running the HTML version I get the runtime exception "Your PlayN application must not be compiled with -XdisableClassMetadata. It breaks TriplePlay stylesheets.".  Having seen [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/playn/5BSCxuULujQ/discussion) on the Google Group I know that I change `pom.xml` in my `html` directory to:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <disableClassMetadata>false</disableClassMetadata>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      ...
```

This makes perfect sense to me.  The problem, however, is that the exception has not gone away!  I have tried `mvn clean` followed by `mvn -Phtml integration-test`.  I am using PlayN and TriplePlay versions 1.5.1.

Could anyone explain why this is happening, or if not, how I might be able to figure out why the setting is not taking effect?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already figured this out, but "mvn clean" does not enable the "html" Maven profile, so it does not actually clean your html build. You need to do either:

```
mvn clean -Phtml
mvn integration-test -Phtml
```

or just:

```
mvn clean integration-test -Phtml
```